# How to find the missing number in a sequence

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a Holy Bible file which starts every line with a verse number (e.g. `1, 2, 3, 4`) and so on. But on certain chapters some verses are skipped or are not present, for example `10, 11, 12, 14`, etc.

Using Notepad++, will it be possible to find out the missing verse numbers with the help of regex?

**Edit:** the range of sequence to lookup is line 1 to 176, since it is the longest chapter in the Bible which is Psalm Chapter 119.

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745017/regex-to-match-either-range-or-list-of-numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a one-off solution, try this:

```
^(\d*0)\..*\n(?!\d*1\.|(?!\d))|
^(\d*1)\..*\n(?!\d*2\.|(?!\d))|
^(\d*2)\..*\n(?!\d*3\.|(?!\d))|
^(\d*3)\..*\n(?!\d*4\.|(?!\d))|
^(\d*4)\..*\n(?!\d*5\.|(?!\d))|
^(\d*5)\..*\n(?!\d*6\.|(?!\d))|
^(\d*6)\..*\n(?!\d*7\.|(?!\d))|
^(\d*7)\..*\n(?!\d*8\.|(?!\d))|
^(\d*8)\..*\n(?!\d*9\.|(?!\d))|
^(\d*9)\..*\n(?!\d*0\.|(?!\d))
```

It's not great, but if you have a line with a number that ends in `6.` for example, then it ensures that the next line has to start in `7.` (so `16.` looks for the next line to start with `17.`, and `111.` looks for `112.`).

You can see an example here: https://regex101.com/r/hO3yQ1/3